# z-fighting problem with hair using image planes

Tags: z-fighting

I'm trying to make a bush out of small videos of waving plants.  I made a mesh with hair and set it to sample the collection containing videos. It looks awesome.  However maybe 2% of the 100 hair/image planes flicker through eachother.  I'm wondering if there is a solution besides re-scrambling the group's seed and testing again.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can download the [G-Scatter addon](https://www.graswald3d.com/gscatter) for free and use it to scatter the planes. In G-Scatter's settings you can set a minimum distance between all scattered assets, so the planes won't touch.